# Worksheet Event - BeforeDoubleClick

Tags: excel, vba

The following code gives me an error and I can't figure out why:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Target.Style = "Good" Then
       Target.Style = "Normal"
    Else
       Target.Style = "Good" 
    End If

    Cancel = True

End Sub
```

When I doubleclick in a cell the error occurs in the line `Target.Style = "Good"` after `Else` telling me

> "Error 450: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

Comment: I tried your code and it worked perfectly. Perhaps your workbook is corrupted.

Comment: It seems that `Good` style does not exist - maybe this is other than English version of Excel.

Comment: Code works for me after I changed `Good` to `Gut` as I have a german excel version. This seems to be a language issue as @BrakNicku stated.